# Android templating engine - like Mustache

Tags: android

I'm searching for a templating engine for Android just like Mustache. I've got a JSON Object containing loads of information, and I've got a linear layout with loads of Textviews in it. Now, I want to be able to fill all those out without having to assign them manually in code. Here's an example of a Textview:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/computer_processor_clock_speed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:text="{{computer.clock_speed}}"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

I know that there's an Android version of Mustache, but all it does is input and output strings, where I want to basically pass it my linear layout and my JSON Object and it'll do the job for me.

So does this exist?